# How to display data from PHP using Jquery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm learning how to use Ajax in Jquery and I have no idea how to display the content that I receive back from the PHP. In the php file I'm just doing some calculations and I'm echoing the result (should I return it instead?), but the code below doesn't return anything. Nothing happens the div stays empty. This is my php code:

```
$totaalPrice = $totaal;
$roundUp =  number_format($totaalPrice, 2, '.', '');
$replace = str_replace(".", ",", $roundUp);
echo "Uw rit kost: € " . $replace . " euro<br>";
```

This is how I built my Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "brain.php",
  data: {km:km, time:time, day:day},
  succes: function(price){
  $('#showPrice').html(price).show(price); //This where I'm trying to display the result.
  },
  error: function(){
   alert('something went wrong..');}
});
```

Comment: Typo: `succes` vs `success`

Comment: Other than that, use `console.log(price)`/your browsers DevConsole to see what you get from that request

Comment: @brombeer Ahh thank you for helping! I removed the typo and the code works completely fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "brain.php",
      data: {km:km, time:time, day:day},
      success: function(price){
      $('#showPrice').html(price);
      },
      error: function(){
       alert('something went wrong..');}
    });
```